# Media Query pattern to manage style by both width and height

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries, fullpage.js

I recently made a site using the [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) package, which essentially makes sections of your site broken into statically sized pages, sized to the full size of the viewport.

What this means is that all the content per section must fit into the viewport size.  Content is not intended to overflow, since any scrolling by the user moves the page to the next section.

This is all fine and good, however I was left with a bit of a challenge on how to make the site responsive to the various screen sizes.  What I ended up doing was designing my css for a very small space, and then for screens that are wider/taller, I would set media queries to cause the text to get bigger in order to take up more space.

However, I found that my paradigm was fraught with error.  Despite trying hard to get all the possible configurations of screen size, I still had problems with text flowing outside of the viewport bounds.  Also, having to account for all the permutations was really "heavy" and not very elegant, and makes me think I didn't come up with a good solution.

There must be a more intuitive media-query pattern to manage this.  Wondering what others have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the easiest solution when dealing with fullpage.js is to make use of the `responsiveWidth` or `responsiveHeight` options the plugin provides.

This combined with some CSS that forces the auto size of the section's height would make it easier.

```
.fp-section,
.fp-slide,
.fp-tableCell{
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Take a look at [this site](http://www.boxreload.com/) using fullpage.js and see how the 2nd section gets bigger on small widths to solve the space problem.
You can see something very similar in http://burntmovie.com/

Regarding the media queries, don't forget you can also use `width` and `height` conditions on the same style:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 890px)  and (max-height: 680px) {
    #section3 img{
        bottom: -50px;
    }
}
```

This can be seen in the [fullpage.js demo page](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).

Comment: ahhh... the responsive option might have been what I was looking for initially.  Good to know.  Fullpage is your work?  Really good stuff!

Comment: I added my answer, but your answer has more interesting information in it, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Others have looked for the technical details for the solution, but I was looking for the pattern.  After some thought, I believe I have the answer I was looking for.  The answer is perhaps simple, but for some reason I struggled initially as I approached it.

For a statically designed site designed with pages that are meant for full-screen, the design will have a aspect-ratio of width and height.  At least, my designer generated the designs according to an implicit screen ratio.  Structuring the media-queries for width and height along that ratio will ensure the content looks good as the screen is resized.

If the width or height gets far out of whack from the ratio, then minor alterations can be done to adjust it, but laying out most of the responsive design along the main axis is where I started.

For me, the design was basically square, so I structured my queries as such:

```
@media (min-width: 501px) and (min-height: 501px) {}
@media (min-width: 701px) and (min-height: 701px) {}
@media (min-width: 901px) and (min-height: 901px) {}
```

Initially, I had nested media queries, and it was getting crazy and ugly.  This made it much simpler and intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Probably with fullpage.js it is impossible to deal with this problem. But try to wrap content of one section by div like below:

html:

```
    <div class="block">
       (...)
    </div>
```

css:

```
    .overflow-block {
        max-height: 80%;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
```

It isn't exactly what you asked, but this solution it will make possible to scroll this block using container's slider.

Comment: My question is really focused on how to make use of CSS and media-queries to manage the styling of my content.  Relying on overflow is not a good idea in general for good design, but also will not work with the fullpage.js package.